# How to merge two tables for select paginate data in peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

if i have two tables

```
class Man:
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()

class Woman:
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()
```

I want get result such as

```
[
    {'name':'a', 'age':18, 'sex':'man'},
    {'name':'b', 'age':20, 'sex':'man'},
    {'name':'c', 'age':20, 'sex':'woman'}
]
```

I have many many data in tables, so what can I write use `peewee` like `merge(table Man, table Woman).order_by(age).paginate(1,20)` to get result.

thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_examples.html#combining-results-from-multiple-queries

There aren't very many examples of doing unions with Peewee, since there is a bit of a disconnect between querying two different tables and expecting to receive two different model classes.

You could also put the data in a single table and use a column to differentiate gender...might be easier.

Comment: thanks for your answer, because it just a simple example for describe the problem. There are still some different fields between two tables...